# undefined reference to 'pruio_new' and 'pruio_config' on beaglebone black

Tags: c, linux, header, debian, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to get the ADC running on beaglebone black. The OS is Debian GNU/Linux 7.7. I'm using C language. When I try to compile the following code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include "pruio_c_wrapper.h"
  #include "pruio_pins.h"

  int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) { 
  PruIo *io = pruio_new(0, 0x98, 0, 1);
  if (io->Errr) {
     printf("Initialisation failed (%s)\n", io->Errr);
     return 1;
  }

  if(pruio_config(io, 0, 0x1FE, 0, 4, 0)){
     printf("Config failed (%s)\n", io->Errr); 
     return 1;
  }


  int a = 0;
  int i;
  while(1){
     printf("\r%12o  %12o  %12o  %12o  %4X %4X %4X %4X %4X %4X %4X %4X\n", io->Gpio[0].Stat, io->Gpio[1].Stat, io->Gpio[2].Stat, io->Gpio[3].Stat, io->Value[1], io->Value[2], io->Value[3], io->Value[4], io->Value[5], io->Value[6], io->Value[7], io->Value[8]);
     fflush(STDIN_FILENO);
     usleep(1000);
   }


  pruio_destroy(io);

       return 0;
  }
```

But I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to 'pruio_new'
undefined reference to 'pruio_config'
```

I installed everything like `FreeBasic` compiler and `pruss driver kit` for `freebasic` and `BBB` and `libpruio`. I also copied all the header files in the same directory as the .c file, including `"pruio_c_wrapper.h"`, `"pruio-pins.h"`, `"pruio.h"` and all the other files in the src directory of `libpruio`. But it doesn't work.

Could you please tell me what to do?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using a `Makefile`? if not, please post your compiler command. Where did you install `libpruio` from?

Comment: no I'm not using Makefile. I use this command:  gcc test.c -o test   and I have put the .c file and all the header files in same directory. I installed libpruio from here: http://www.freebasic-portal.de/dlfiles/554/libpruio-0.0.2.tar.bz2

Comment: did you compile `libpruio`?

Answer (score 2):

libfb is the FreeBASIC run-time library. When you want to compile against the old libpruio-0.0.x versions, you'll need an old FreeBASIC installation from

www{dot}freebasic-portal.de/dlfiles/452/bbb_fbc-0.0.2.tar.xz

Which installs /usr/local/lib/freebasic/libfb.so.

See the libpruio-0.0.x C example codes for compiler command line arguments (ie. header section of io_input.c).

But I recommend to use the new version libpruio-0.2 from (the last post links to the documentation of this new version)

http://www.freebasic-portal.de/dlfiles/592/libpruio-0.2.tar.bz2

which doesn't have this pitfalls, gcc compiles without FB installation, and provides new features like pinmuxing, PWM, CAP. There're small bugs in this versions C header, which is now named pruio.h: a missing enum and a copy / paste bug regarding a function name. See this thread for details:

http://www.freebasic.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=22501

BR

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I downloaded it, the binaries are in `libpruio-0.0.2/libpruio/src/c_wrapper` and so are the include files, copy the headers and `libpruio.so` to the same directory where the `test.c` file resides, and then

1. For the includes, you need to to append `libpruio`'s include directory to the compiler command using `-I.` then you can do

   ```
   #include <pruio_c_wrapper.h>
   #include <pruio_pins.h>
   ```
2. You need to append the library to the linker command, with

   ```
   -L. -lpruio
   ```

your complete compilation command will be then

```
gcc -o test -I. -L. -lpruio test.c
```

Comment: I copied all the files in the `libpruio-0.0.2/libpruio/src/c_wrapper`, including `libpruio.so` to the same directory where test.c is. I followed all your instructions but now I get like 30 errors looking like:  `./libpruio.so: undefined reference to 'lots of things' ` What should I do?

Comment: @Melika That means you need to add more libraries to the linker command, but which libraries they are depends on what `undefined reference`'s you get.

Comment: You mean I need to copy some other headers to the same directory as test.c? I copied all the file related to `libpruio`. The errors seem to be related to `pruss driver kit` and `FreeBasic`. So I need to add their header files to the directory as well right?

Comment: I used `-lprussdrv` and the errors were half! I then used `-lfb` but now it says: `cannot find -lfb`

Comment: I think as `-lpruio` includes the libraries of `libpruio` and `-lprussdrv` includes the libraries of `pruss driver kit`, maybe `-lfb` includes the libraries of `FreeBasic`, since almost all the errors I currently get is related to `FreeBasic`

Comment: Is there a `libfb.so` in `/usr/lib`?

Comment: no. the only `.so` file here is `preloadable_libintl.so`. everything else is directory

Comment: You must search in `libpruio` site, they have [this](http://users.freebasic-portal.de/tjf/Projekte/libpruio/doc/html/_cha_preparation.html), you have all the instructions you need right there.